# Resolution Inference Rule Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, logic, artificial-intelligence

I have the following doubt in the Resolution Inference Rule.

1* In `for each Ci, Cj in clauses do` , does each Ci and Cj necessarily contain complimentary symbols (ex. one contains A and the other contains ~A) ?

2* In the above example , what if both clauses have the same symbol (ex A and A). Should I consider it for inference? If so , what result does it return?

3* when does the `if new ⊆ clauses then return false` run? After all the clauses have been explored?

4* What is the use of `if new ⊆ clauses then return false` ?

5* What is the use of `if new ⊆ clauses then return false` ?

```
 function PL-RESOLUTION(KB,α) returns true or false
     inputs: KB, the knowledge base, a sentence α in propositional logic, 
             the query, a sentence in propositional logic 
     clauses <--- the set of clauses in the CNF representation of KB ∧ ¬α
     new <--- {}
     loop do
        for each Ci, Cj in clauses do
            resolvents <----- PL-RESOLVE(Ci, Cj)
            if resolvents contains the empty clause then return true
            new <--- new ∪ resolvents
        if new ⊆ clauses then return false
        clauses <---- clauses  ∪ new
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. No, you can't apply resolution in that case.
3. Well, why shouldn't it happen?
4. I guess it's to avoid infinite loops (in that case you return to the conditions at the previous iteration)
5. Same question?

More about 1 and 2. The idea for resolution is that if you have (A v B) ^ (not A v C) then you can safely infer that B or C are true (informally because A is either true or false). If you have (A v B) ^ (A v C) you can't apply the same reasoning.